# Spring JPA Query - Replace negative values in result set

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA. I'm using a custom JPQL query to get the data I need.

The following is my method repository:

```
/**
  * SELECT sku, SUM(real_allocation - logical_allocation)
  * FROM stock
  * WHERE warehouse_brand = '?'
  * GROUP BY (warehouse_brand, sku);
  */

@Query(value = "SELECT new it.reply.retail.oms.common.api.inventory.CumulativeInventoryItem " +
               "(s.pk.sku, SUM(s.realAllocation - s.logicalAllocation)) " +
               "FROM Stock s WHERE s.pk.whsCode IN :warehouses GROUP BY (s.pk.sku)")
Page<CumulativeInventoryItem> getCumulativeInventory(List<String> warehouses, Pageable pageable);
```

and the `CumulativeInventoryItem` custom object is the following one:

```
public class CumulativeInventoryItem {

    private String sku;
    private Long cumulativeQty;

}
```

The result set I obtain, sometimes, contains negative values for the `cumulativeQty` attribute which need to be replaced with 0 instead.

Is it possible to replace these values using ad-hoc query or I need to replace them once I get the result set back from my JPA method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0

the CASE WHEN THEN ELSE combination can be use there.

May can you try

```
SUM(CASE WHEN (s.realAllocation - s.logicalAllocation < 0) THEN 0 ELSE (s.realAllocation - s.logicalAllocation)))
```

instead of

```
SUM(s.realAllocation - s.logicalAllocation)
```